# Drilling down into Python Dictionary, one level at a time

Tags: python, dictionary

This seems like it should be easy, but I can't figure it out.  This a piece from a JSON file loaded here:

```
with open('states.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

How do I just print the state names? Or just the names and abbreviations?

```
{
    "states": [
        {
            "name": "Alabama",
            "abbreviation": "AL",
            "area_codes": [
                "205",
                "251",
                "256",
                "334",
                "938"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Alaska",
            "abbreviation": "AK",
            "area_codes": [
                "907"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Arizona",
            "abbreviation": "AZ",
            "area_codes": [
                "480",
                "520",
                "602",
                "623",
                "928"
            ]
        }
}
```

Tried this:

```
print(data["states"])  #prints everything
print(data["states"]["name"]) #errors out
print(data["states"]["name"][0]) #prints just first record
```

Also tried this, which again prints everything:

```
for state in data['states']:
    print(state)
```

Comment: what is the return type of “states”

Comment: data returns <class 'dict'>.  Sorry, I left out some pieces to the code which I have added.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of the following should work:

```
state_names = [state["name"] for state in data["states"]]
print("\n".join(state_names))
```

or for names and abbreviations:

```
names_and_abbrev = ["{}: {}".format(state["abbreviation"], state["name"]) for state in data["states"]]
print("\n".join(names_and_abbrev))
```

Result:

```
AL: Alabama
AK: Alaska
AZ: Arizona
```